# Sorting algorithm when already in order

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Which algorithm is fastest if an array is already sorted? Insertsort, Quicksort, or Mergesort?

//needmorecharactersformorecharactersneedmorecharacters

Comment: try searching. you'll love it.

Answer (score 0):

bubble-sort with checking.
like this....

```
for i = 1..n-1
  bool changed = false
  for j <- i+1..n
    if a[i] > a[j] then
      swap (a[i], a[j])
      changed = true
  if changed is false then
    break
```